# Central Limit Theorem VS Normal Model

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I just had a quick question regarding the Central Limit Theorem and Normal Model. I am in an elementary probability course and we have learnt that the CLT is as follows:

$$ Z = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + ... X_n - n\mu}{SD\sqrt{n}}$$

I understand that after I use this equation, I have a standardized value that I can use the Normal Model on. However in some problems, I see that my prof. just uses the standard way of standardizing values. I am not sure when to use each one...

$$ Z = \frac{X -\mu}{SD}$$

I do not understand when I should use each one and help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks :)

Comment: However in some problems, I see that my prof. just uses the standard way of standardizing values.

--------this sentence does not make sense to me

Comment: What I meant to say was, in some CLT problems, my prof simply standardizes the values given by the second (more familiar) equation. However, the CLT equation is slightly different and I was wondering when I should differentiate between the two!

Comment: why does it say (Z=.... ) / ?

Comment: also $n-\mu$. what?

Comment: My mistake, I corrected it!

Comment: I am more concerned with $n-\mu$....

Comment: There is no $n-\mu$.  You must have written it down, because your professor would never write that.

Comment: Yes, I changed it! My mistake

Comment: what is $X$? it is not $X$ either... there need to be a square root of n here somewhere.

Comment: Not in the second equation. That is simply standardizing a value $X$. No need for square root of $n$, thats in the first equation.

Comment: you have not defined any of these terms you have used, including you changed an $n$ into an $X$ in the final expression without explaining what it is. I cannot see how someone could have provided you with a correct answer to a question which made no sense. Anyway, you don't need to explain anything else to me, if you are happy.

Comment: @Lost1, he's in an elementary course so he's most likely not used to the rigor and necessity normally required for formal proof and problem solving, so I think we just had to kind of make some assumptions as to what he was asking for.  At least that is what I though when I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$.
Then
$$E[Y]=E[\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}]=\sum_{i=1}^n{E[X_i]}=\sum_{i=1}^n{\mu_x}=n\mu_x.$$
And 
$$Var[Y]=Var[\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}]=\sum_{i=1}^n{Var[X_i]}=\sum_{i=1}^n{\sigma_x^2}=n\sigma_x^2.$$  So the standard deviation is $\sigma_x\sqrt{n}.$

Thus, we have $Z=\frac{Y-n\mu}{\sigma_x\sqrt{n}}$.  Multiplying by $1=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$ we get
$$Z=\frac{\frac{Y}{n}-\mu_x}{\frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Since you're just multiplying the first expression by $1$, both expressions are valid.  Most use the second one because $\frac{Y}{n}$ is an average of samples.  Most problems will give you the pertinent information, such as the mean of the summed random samples is this, in which case you can use the first formula, or they might tell you the mean of the average of random samples in which you use the second.

Comment: How is that final expression you wrote down equal to $(n-\mu)/\sqrt{\sigma}$?  $n-\mu$???????? when have you ever seen a formula with $n-\mu$ in it? $n$ is the number of sample and $\mu$ is mean, to subtract them is dimensionally incorrect for a start.

Comment: Ah, yes the paragraph you wrote makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: your n in your original question is most likely a typo.  Problems dealing with this in general will give you information which pertains to the summed random variables or the average random variable created by dividing the summed random variables by the number of random variables.

Answer (score 1):

The CLT, basically says that, independently of the original distribution, a variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ the mean distribution converges to a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$.

Your second formula (that I believe that you want say $Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$) is to standarize your normal. Let's say we have three random variable:

```
X ~ N(0,1)
Y ~ N(1,5)
Z ~ N(7,42) (sorry, but I don't know how to put multiple line of formula :()
```

For this variables, he have that:

$P(X < 1) = P(Y < 6) = P(Z < 49)$

But we can't compute this probabilites by hand, so we use a table. But, we can't have a table for all possible normal distributions, so we standarize it to a Normal(0,1).

I hope that it helps you (and sorry for the bad english :()!

Comment: you have to have $\frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{n}}$ in your Z-transform...

Comment: The $\sigma$ in my Z-transform is the SD from $X$, not from the original variable. If $X$ is a mean of some other variable (W), so you're rigth, $\sigma = \sigma_w/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Oh yeah.  My mistake...